# Upload image from local drive and not Web Form using PHP

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to upload an image to my `mysql` database. I am trying the below with no avail.

```
<?php
global $mysqli;
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "mypass", "mydb");
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
}

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents('C:/wamp64/www/images/img1.jpg')); 
$image_name = addslashes("imagename");
$query = "INSERT INTO info ('image', 'image_name') VALUES ('$image', '$image_name')";

if (!mysql_query($query))
    { 
    echo "Something went wrong!"; 
    }
?>
```

I get the below error:

> Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will
>   be removed  in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in
>   C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using
>   password: N O) in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established
>   in C:\wamp 64\www\index.php on line 13 Something went wrong!

However, if I remove the code starting from $image, I get not errors, meaning that the database connection is successful. There seems to be something wrong in the second part of the code, and I'm afraid the error might be misleading.

Comment: That warning is pretty clear: you need to connect to your database using the proper credentials before you can execute a query

Comment: @rickdenhaan I updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Do not use string concatenation like this for SQL queries. Code like this is inherently vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use PDO or a similar API which supports parameterised queries.

Comment: You're connecting using `mysqli`, but querying using `mysql`. Those are separate things, you need to query using `mysqli` as well

Comment: As others pointed out, you need to use `$mysqli->query()`. So you should change `mysql_query($query)` to `$mysqli->query($query)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not use string concatenation for SQL queries.
- Look up PDO
- You're connecting using MySQLi, but your query command is MySQL. The error is extremely clear.